# PHP pass default argument to function

Tags: php, function, default

I have a PHP function, like this:

```
function($foo = 12345, $bar = false){}
```

What I want to do, is call this function with the default argument of $foo passed, but $bar set to true, like this (more or less)

```
function(DEFAULT_VALUE, true);
```

How do I do it? How do I pass an argument as a function's default value without knowing that value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What I am thinking right now.. might there not also be a value like void? I mean, null is a value, but, at least in Java, the nothingness can be brought one step further, by using void. At least as the return value of a function, if it not only returns null, but actually nothing.

Comment: there is no such "void" in PHP. `""` and `null` are identical

Comment: Incredible that so many people on this page completely missed the point of the question (I thought it was quite clear).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not natively possible in PHP. There are workarounds like using arrays to pass all parameters instead of a row of arguments, [but they have massive downsides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112913/should-my-php-functions-accept-an-array-of-arguments-or-should-i-explicitly-reque).

The best manual workaround that I can think of is defining a constant with an arbitrary value that can't collide with a real value. For example, for a parameter that can never be `-1`:

```
define("DEFAULT_ARGUMENT", -1);
```

and test for that:

```
function($foo = DEFAULT_ARGUMENT, $bar = false){}
```

Answer (score 3):

put them the other way round:

```
function($bar = false, $foo = 12345){}

function(true);
```

Comment: I can't, for I already use this function in a huge lot of places :D

Comment: @arik-so refractor then, freddie's way the way to do it, that is exactly what i was going to answer

Comment: usually you don't have at too many places those most extreme last parameters, and if you have, probably they should be on the more 'front' places

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach to this is that `if (is_null($foo))` the function replaces it with the default. Use null, empty string, etc. to "skip" arguments. This is how most built-in PHP functions that need to skip arguments do it.

```
<?php
function($foo = null, $bar = false)
    {
    if (is_null($foo))
        {
        $foo = 12345;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: well, in my case, the argument being a string, null is an acceptable value ^^ Actually, in my case, more or less anything is an acceptable value.

Comment: Ah, this is much better than my answer, I actually have used this before but I forgot about it. I'm sure some purists would argue with the approach though.

Comment: @arik-so you can do a type comparison as well to see if `NULL` is actually `NULL` and not an empty string (a la  `===`)

Answer (score 3):

PHP can't do exactly that, so you'll have to work around it. Since you already need the function in its current form, just define another:

```
function blah_foo($bar)
{
    blah(12345, $bar);
}

function blah($foo = 12345, $bar = false) { }
```

Comment: that sounds interesting, too ^^ considering that any value is acceptable, I think your approach is the best.

Comment: I'd be very careful with introducing new functions to the code for something like this, though. You need to document them, keep them in mind... It's very easy to build sub-optimal code this way

Answer (score -2):

i think, it's better sorted based on the argument that the most frequently changed, `$bar` for example, we put it first,

```
function foo( $bar = false, $foo = 12345){
// blah blah...
}
```

so when you want to pass `$bar` to `true`, and `$foo` to `12345`, you do this,

```
foo(true);
```