# Building a good object orientated application? Function params or Object Params

Tags: php, jquery, coding-style

I have written a PHP application that uses Objects heavily.  Added, deleting, updating etc.. rows in my database.  I want it to conform to a easy to read standard for future developers and the possibility of open sourcing the code.  Which is easier for you?  Assume variables are public.

```
$tablename = new tablenameClass;
result= $tablename->addrow($POST,$AdditionalStuff,$Settings);
```

or using the object

```
$tablename = new tablenameClass;
$tablename->AdditionalStuff = array(whatever);
$tablename->Settings = array(settings);
result= $tablename->addrow($POST);
```

So this question is more about convention then anything else.  Sorry I know the code is broken.

I really like the way jQuery does it.

```
tablename(array({
    thing:stuff,
    thing2:stuff2
    }));
```

Comment: maybe....`array(thing->stuff,thing2->stuff2)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should my PHP functions accept an array of arguments or should I explicitly request arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112913/should-my-php-functions-accept-an-array-of-arguments-or-should-i-explicitly-requ)

Comment: yes and no.  This is in regards to Objects.

Comment: You're absolutely right - your question is significantly different. Hopefully some of the points brought up in that question are insightful anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd example is much easier to read and understand...`AdditionalStuff` and `Settings` are defined right there.

The 2nd example also seems to fall in line with **high cohesion** as you have members supporting a well-focused role and/or responsibility.

Your 1st example has a method that accepts multiple arguments, which isn't necessarily bad, but in the 2nd example, this same method is reduced to only needing one argument which *seems* to promote more cohesion in the method.